# AngularJS update $scope from other controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following issue:

In my controller I have something like:

```
$scope.current = 0;
```

And I have some directive who is looking like this:

```
angular.module('myAPP')
    .directive('post', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                post: '=',
                index: '='
            },

        link: function(scope) {
          //update the $scope.current here
        },
        templateUrl: 'components/blog/post.html'
    };
});
```

Can someone explain me whats the best way to do this, its possible to update the $scope inside the link function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [event handlers](http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/04/angularjs-notifying-about-changes-from-services-to-controllers/). It should look like this:

```
angular.module('myAPP')
    .directive('post', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                post: '=',
                index: '='
            },

        link: function(scope) {
          $scope.on('my-event', function(value){
             $scope.current = value;
          });
          //update the $scope.current here
        },
        templateUrl: 'components/play/questions/simple-question.html'
    };
});
```

And in your controller you will send notification event to your directive:

```
$scope.emit('my-event', $scope.current);
```

If your directive lies outside of your controller, than you need to use `$rootScope` instead.

Comment: I am glad I could help:)

Answer (score 6):

Your directive has an isolate `scope`.

To change `current` from directive, you have to bind it with directive scope variable like this

Like this

**html**

```
<post index="current"></post>
```

**js**

```
link: function(scope) {
   scope.index=2;
},
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do this. See the scope section under https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile on how this bidirection `=` binding works